# Stability adding matrix with imaginary eigenvalues.

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, rotations

For an autonomous system:

$$x'= Ax$$

This solution is asymptotically stable as $t \to \infty$ if and only if for all eigenvalues $λ$ of $A$, $\Re(λ) < 0$.

In that case, would the system:

$$x'= Ax + Bx$$

keep stable, if all the eigenvalues of B are pure imaginary?

Comment: Welcome to MSE, here is a guide on how to use MathJax: https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference

Comment: This would depend on which of A and B is more subjected to De Morgan's law. Thus one would be a weak derivative and a spectral radius would be found. Usually the analytically limited of the two is chosen to be imaginary, while the catagorically limited i.e point-wise convergent is real.

Comment: For what it's worth, I have no idea what Cppg's comment means.

Answer (score 2):

No, in general there's no reason to expect the eigenvalues of the sum of two matrices to be equal to or even controlled by the sum of the eigenvalues of the two matrices (except for the fact that traces add). Explicitly, take

$$A = \left[ \begin{array}{cc} -1 & t \\ 0 & -1\end{array} \right], B = \left[ \begin{array}{cc} 0 & 1 \\ -1  & 0 \end{array} \right].$$

where $t$ is an indeterminate. The eigenvalues of $A$ are $-1, -1$ and the eigenvalues of $B$ are $i, -i$, but

$$A + B = \left[ \begin{array}{cc} -1 & t + 1 \\ -1 & -1 \end{array} \right]$$

has characteristic polynomial $\lambda^2 + 2 \lambda + (t + 2)$ and hence eigenvalues

$$\lambda = \frac{-4 \pm \sqrt{4 - 4(t + 2)}}{2}.$$

By taking $t \to - \infty$ we can arrange for the larger eigenvalue to get not only positive but arbitrarily large.

Things are better if you assume either that $A$ and $B$ commute or that $A$ and $B$ are self-adjoint.

Comment: Thanks, I was asking for a matrix with negative eigenvalues, not positive. But your example can be applied to demonstrate that my statement is not correct.

Comment: Yeah, sorry, for some reason I thought you wanted eigenvalues less than $1$, but as you say it's easy to fix.